# inputs need to equal zero before action

Tags: javascript, html

how can i get each input to equal zero before it is touched so that i dont get an error until every input is completed and not have it show in the input field. Also this is for money and im struggling to get the two decimal point thing down. thank you

```
<td>Subtotal</td>
<td class="total" id="tot" for="tot">
<input type="total" id="total">
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction()
{
var answer = document.getElementById('total');
var n = 0
var x = document.getElementById('itemprice');
var y = document.getElementById('itemprice1');
var z = document.getElementById('itemprice2');
//var d = document.getElementsById('itemprice3');

// parseFloat converts to values, otherwise you'll concatenate the strings.
answer.value = parseFloat(x[0].value) + parseFloat(y[0].value) + parseFloat(z[0].value); // + d.value;
                                                                }

                                                                </script>

                                                                </td>
```

Comment: You should probably avoid working with floats when dealing with money - in js if you run `0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3` it comes out as false due to rounding errors.  Better to multiply the money by 100 to get integers, do your math, then divide by 100 to bring it back to decimal form.  To get it to exactly 2 decimal places, you can `your_variable.toFixed(2)`

Answer (score 1):

give the item prices a zero default value:

```
<input type="total" id="itemprice" value="0.00">
```